# What is the phrase or expression which has the word ‘finger’ in it and means very easily or quickly

Tags: phrase-requests, proverb-requests

> Long ago the Internet could not be accessed ….

I am looking for a word to use in the above sentence. I want it to mean ‘easily’ and ‘quickly’. I remember there was a phrase or proverb which had the word ‘finger’ in it.

Comment: ["at your fingertips"?](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/at-your-fingertips)

Comment: "Long **time** ago, the Internet was not at the touch of a button" seems more appropriate

Comment: Let your fingers do the walking....

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I think you mean '**a** long time ago'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey yes, you're right. It was a silly slip up of mine.

Comment: The absolute minimum-effort "finger" idiom in U.S. English is "without lifting a finger." It doesn't seem literally applicable to accessing the Internet long ago, however.

Comment: way off topic, but the sentence is kind of quaint in a way: the easy access to the internet you are referencing is perhaps 25 years. We can argue that means "long ago," but what you are really talking about is the entirety of human history prior to this, there was no access to internet (let alone *easy access to it*). In this context, your thesis is a massive understatement.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: For the record "Long ago" is fine (if a little formal).

Comment: "Long ago the Internet could not be accessed, but then somebody pulled their finger out"

Answer (score 11):

How about:

**Long ago the Internet was not *at everybody’s fingertips*.**

It’s slightly awkward in this example sentence — it works better when the active agent is more explicit (e.g. “When I was a kid, we didn’t have the internet at our fingertips.”)  But otherwise it seems to fit exactly what you have in mind: it means something is easily and quickly accessible at any time, and involves fingers.

(Also suggested by [Esther](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/369152/) in comments on the question.)

Answer (score 7):

There is a possibility of using  a fixed expression  that has "fingers" in it, but it would probably be better to use it in the present case as introduced by another fixed expression ("*just like that*").

> ([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/The_Dead_Life/zJDcDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22just+like+that+at+the%22&pg=PA252&printsec=frontcover)) … turned back over his shoulder but not toward me, stared for what seemed like a whole lot longer than a couple seconds as if he'd tranced out just like that, at the snap of the fingers, as if he was staring suddenly at something in

- Long ago the Internet could not be accessed *just like that, at a/the snap of the fingers*

Comment: At or in the snap of the fingers?

Comment: @Sasan Both are used, and you might look up the various contexts found on the pages of examples found [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+a+snap+of+the%2Cat+a+snap+of+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20a%20snap%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20a%20snap%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cin%20a%20snap%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20a%20snap%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0). It seems to me, beforehand, that both are equally correct, but as "in" shows more definitely the idea of a very short lapse of time, it is possibly better in this case.

Comment: @LPH I suspect that 'in the snap of the fingers' is a US usage, only 'at the snap of the fingers' is familiar to me in BrE. To me 'a snap of the fingers' is a command or initiation like 'the press of a button' rather than a specification of a short period of time. The expression for a short period of time is 'in the blink of an eye'.

Comment: @BoldBen I am also familiar with the idea that "at" relates to a signal associated with a command,  that must be right then, but I can't say anything about US or British usage for either preposition.

Comment: [Your Dictionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/snap-of-a-finger) has: << Snap-of-a-finger definition: Very easily, with little effort. >> But the example they give sounds odd to my (UK) ears. I'm used to 'at the snap of a finger'. eg << "You lose a treasure trove like that, it's not exactly replaceable at the snap of a finger," Ms. Solomon said. >> [[The New York Times; LudvigGuru](https://ludwig.guru/s/snap+of+a+finger)]

Comment: *"At the touch of a finger"* could also work.  Too similar to make another answer though.

Comment: @BoldBen Isn't it more common in the UK to talk of ‘_clicking_’ fingers, rather than snapping them?

Answer (score 1):

"like snapping your fingers" or "at the snap of a finger" or other constructions that refer to [snapping fingers](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/snapping+your+fingers), [also this](https://www.yourdictionary.com/snap-of-a-finger).  This conveys the idea that it is easy and basically instantaneous.  It may also imply that no extra/additional equipment is needed beyond what is already on hand.

Comment: I think Dave's getting closest, and I think "with the snap of a finger" is about ease as in power or authority, rather than as in simplicity, and to me "quickly" deals with the split second needed to make the decision or give the order, rather than the time taken to achieve whatever it is.